# Monitoring Ryzen 2700X CPU Temperatures in Ubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 5.0.11)

Tags: temperature, amd-processor, sensors, lm-sensors, amd-ryzen

How can we monitor the CPU temperature of an AMD Ryzen 7 2700X in Ubuntu 18.04? The kernel has already been updated to `5.0.11-050011-generic`, yet `sudo sensors-detect` shows nothing being detected, and `sensors` do not show CPU temps.

**Output of `sensors`**

```
nouveau-pci-1f00
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.91 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +1.19 V)
temp1:        +38.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +30.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +40.5°C
```

**Output of `uname -r`**

```
5.0.11-050011-generic
```

**Output of `lscpu`**

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               8
Model name:          AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             3399.907
BogoMIPS:            8399.77
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate sme ssbd sev ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca
```

**Output of `sudo sensors-detect`**

```
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7A40 [2.0]
# Board: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. B450I GAMING PLUS AC (MS-7A40)
# Kernel: 5.0.11-050011-generic x86_64
# Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor (23/8/2)

...


Sorry, no sensors were detected.
Either your system has no sensors, or they are not supported, or
they are connected to an I2C or SMBus adapter that is not
supported. If you find out what chips are on your board, check
http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices for driver status.
```

Answer (score 2):

Replying to old question but as it seems issue still not resolved:

Check:

https://github.com/electrified/asus-wmi-sensors

Resolved my case with same chip and ROG Crosshair VII Hero, but also works with other MBs

Comment: Can you explain important steps to solve this issue? Link-only answer aren't best answer, notably if the link would become dead